# jMockitの「Warning: Redundant recording」というコンソール出力を抑制したい

Tags: java, eclipse, jmockit

jMockit 1.28を使っています。

Expectationsの記述で以下のように書くと、`Warning: Redundant recording`という警告がコンソールに出力されます。

```
@Test
public void test(@Mocked Hoge hoge) {
    
    new Expectations() {{
        hoge.get();
        result = Collections.emptyList();
    }};
    
    assertThat(hoge.get().isEmpty()).isEqualTo(true);
}

public static class Hoge {
    public List<String> get() {
        return Arrays.asList("aa");
    }
}
```

この警告がなぜ出てくるのかいまいち掴めない（どうやらこのケースの場合、`result =` を書かなくても良い？）のですが、Eclipse上でコンソールウィンドウが毎回表示されてJUnitの結果が隠れてしまうため、とても鬱陶しいです。
この出力を抑制することはできないでしょうか？

なお、`result =` を省略する、という手段は取りたくないです。
書き忘れなのかどうか、テストコードが読み手にとって分かりにくくなってしまうので。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問文のコードを実行してみましたが、現時点での最新バージョン(と思われる)

- JUnit: 5.6.2
- JMockit: 1.49

では再現しませんでした。

- [Warning: Redundant recording and confused cascading #352](https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/352) - jmockit/jmockit1

というissueを見つけたので

- JUnit: 4.13
- JMockit: 1.28

で試したところ、たしかにそのようなメッセージが出力されました。
従って、issueに書かれている通り、JMockit特定バージョンで発現するバグであると思われます。

対処方法は、JMockitのバージョンを上げる、ということになります。
([リリースノート](https://jmockit.github.io/changes.html)からは1.29で修正されているように読めますが、試したところ、メッセージが出力されなくなっているのは1.30以降のようです…？)

Comment: 詳しく検証までしていただき、ありがとうございます！